# Where do I insert my code?

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I need to insert a conditional is_user_logged_in() on my page.php but I am not familiar with codes, so I don't know if the whole condition should be inserted before or after a specific line of the existent code that came with my wordpress theme. I would appreciate your assistance on that. I already have the code for the conditional. I just don't want where the code should start.

```
<?php
    // Caso o usuário esteja logado
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
?>
    Aqui você coloca o seu conteúdo, normalmente é a função do WordPress
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php
    // Caso o usuário não esteja logado
    else :
?>
    "OK, caro coleguinha, faça login para ver o conteúdo" ou alguma mensagem do tipo
    ou até mesmo um form para o usuário fazer o login.
<?php
    // Aqui acaba a brincadeira
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply PHP the if else statement is as follows:

```
if(condition == true) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my question is: I have to insert above code on another page of a WordPress website.  Where (which line) should I insert that code? Before the Line 1 on page.php of after the last Line on page.php or somewhere in the middle.  Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: From what I see in this code (that is if it is correct), it should be inserted in the middle. Unfortunately I am not able to help you on that. You may add more information as to which page you want to insert this to get better help. Are there more instructions from the source you got this code from?

Comment: I have the page.php code. But I would need to create a new thread to be able to submit the code between { }.  Should I do that?

Comment: Above code was sent to me by a friend to help me because I have a problem with my wordpress page that needs to be password protected.  Once the user enters the passw, it stays open forever, even if browser is closed and cookies are deleted.  So he told me that above code should be inserted in the wordpress template to solve the problem.

Comment: I would suggest to go back to that friend and ask for help. You can of course post your page.php with the codeblock and see if somebody here can help. Sorry I am not of good use here.

Comment: NP Tks for ur prompt follow-up

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code any where and in any page in wordpress.
please go through this,Hope this may help you.

```
 <?php
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   echo 'This is Registered User';
   } else {
   echo 'This is non-registered user';
   }
 ?>
```